# Loading resources only once but make them available for every request

Tags: php

I have php file with some array:

```
<?php
return array (
    'some' => 500,
    'some2' => 500,
    'description' => 'Bla bla bla',
    'langs' => 
    array (
        1 => 'php',
        2 => 'java',
    ),
    'users' => 
    array (
        2 => 
        array (
            'x' => 3435,
            'y' => 3852,
            'z' => 6,
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
            'x' => 1700,
            'y' => 1070,
            'z' => 733,
        ),
    ),
);
```

The problem is that this file is really big - I've tried memcache, apc etc. but loading the page (at localhost) takes almost 10 seconds.
So here is my question. Is it possible to make array in this file accessible but without loading it at every page request? Make it as global or something?
I know it's because of characteristics of php itself so if it can be done using some other web language I'm ready to learn it instead of bothering with php.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data in the array exactly? Do you need ALL the data from it in order to display your page properly? You could use ajax calls on demand to just fetch the part of the array you need.

Comment: I would look at reducing the data structure size first (although without seeing what you mean by 'really big' I don't know what to recommend). Tackle the cause of the problem rather than the symptoms. Also, are you sure it is the loading of this data structure which is causing the slowdown?

Comment: Java for example can run as a server (e.g. via Tomcat) access data across sessions and requests. If you want to use PHP, you have also the option to store that data into a database, which makes it easier to retrieve only those parts which are necessary for the current request.

Comment: use session to store the array

Comment: Really big = ~1MB. I'm sure this is casing slowdown. I do need to load all the data (trying to extend someone's else code) - loading all the data to list object. When I read answers I thing the best solution will be to rewrite whole object not to load all data but fetch small portions of data from database. I have no idea how to  'reduce data structure size' - php file almost has the same size as db tables.

Answer (score 1):

APC is a way to go.
If it failed you - then you did something wrong. Time to try again.

Also, it's just a nonsense to store large amounts of data in the code.
Find yourself a reliable storage and use it instead of this silly php code.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way PHP works, no, not really - each request invokes a separate PHP process that generates the response for that request, and thus without involving some kind of other persistent external process, you'd need to load the structure every time since processes don't generally share resources.

Is it possible to move this data to a separate process and do whatever data lookups you need without actually creating the data structure in PHP? (For instance, storing it in a database and running queries, or storing it in a lightweight custom application that accepts RPC requests, etc?)

Do you actually need to construct such a large data structure of PHP objects? Are you sending all of this data to the client, or just looking up specific items from it? More detail on what exactly this data is, what it's being used for, and why it has to be so large would help us to provide further advice.

Comment: Nowdays PHP is not like it was a decade ago. PHP can cache bytecode, so, with another request you may find this code loaded and even parsed.

Comment: OP states that they're already working with APC (which is effectively  a bytecode cache), so if they're still having problems, obviously bytecode caching hasn't solved their problem.

Comment: I'd dare to say it's NOT apc fault.

Comment: Nor would I say it's APC's fault, nor does my answer. I'm assuming you're the one who downvoted it, but I don't think you actually read what the answer said. Regardless of whether the structure is cached as bytecode or not, each individual request is still going to have to deal with a giant data structure, and PHP simply isn't optimized for that.

Comment: Running separated process is not possible. The best idea for now is to rewrite whole object to use database.

Comment: Then yeah, I'd suggest breaking the object up into a more normalized form, storing it in a database, and just querying for the precise information you need from it. The database engine itself can work as your 'separate process'.

Answer (score 0):

as far as php goes, its not possible unless you include it in every page, but why dont you make an API and make sure only the vars that you need are requested? that way its easier to load the page (I am assuming that the array is being fetched from a database considering its size).